# connecting two routers via serial cards

Tags: networking, subnet

on my current router cisco 2811 i have two subnets /30(fe0)  and /27(fe1) ...i want to add /25 but i am told i need an external card: Cisco 2-Port Fast Ethernet Layer 3 HWIC. since thats very expensive i have another cisco 2811 i can use. i am thinking about buying 2 serial cards which i could connect these two routers and place my /25 subnet on one of the free FE ports of the second router. these subnets are public IPs so i cant just move things around that easy since i have dedicated IPs to clients.

questions
1)will this work ? connecting two routers of the same kind 
2)are there any performance issues?

running a small hosting company

thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that the best option is buy a cheap switch that support trunks like Cisco sf300 or C2950, make 3 vlans and create 3 subinterface in C28XX one for each subnet.